# "A non-numeric value encountered" laravel5.1 php7.1 dompdf 0.8

Tags: laravel-5.1, dompdf, php-7.1

I understood that this error was already solved but i don't manage to fix it, so sorry and thanks for your advises:
I'm working on a Laravel 5.1 project (FusionInvoice) and use dompdf to create pdf files. My aim is to use php7.1 for this project.

After enable php7.1 I had the "A non-numeric value encountered" error 
so i did the easy installation procedure of dompdf, with composer method (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) to fix it using the dompdf 0.8.1 release. My requierements seems ok.

Now i have this error:

> FatalThrowableError in domPDF.php line 30: Class 'DOMPDF' not found

we are talking about this file "app/Support/PDF/Drivers/domPDF.php" and this function:

```
private function getPdf($html)
    {
        $pdf = new \DOMPDF();
        $pdf->set_paper($this->paperSize, $this->paperOrientation);
        $pdf->load_html($html);
        $pdf->render();

        return $pdf;
    }
```

I understood that the "new \DOMPDF();" is calling this file '/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php' to build his object.
so i tried this : "new \Dompdf\Dompdf();"

and i'm back to the first place:

> ErrorException in Page.php line 499: A non-numeric value encountered

Does someone knows how i can solve this issue ? Thanks...

Comment: did you added dompdf to aliases/providers? did you clean your config cache?

Comment: Hello and thanks. I'm using "php artisan config:clear" and 
"php artisan cache:clear". Is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

Please check dompdf version and compare with php and laravel version

check this https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/294

Comment: Hello, thanks for this answer, it did the trick. I don't really understand why because i tried before the release but maybe i didn't use the rigth procedure.

Comment: The fix is in the dompdf:0.7.x@dev version, for it to work properly i used: 1 > remove the require : dompf line from your composer.json file, 2 > do "composer update" , 3 > do "composer require dompdf/dompdf:0.7.x@dev --update-with-dependencies"